# Using validate.js with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am using `Twitter Bootstrap v3.3.4` to create a modal login form. I want to use the validate.js plugin for jQuery to validate the form before I send the data via `AJAX`. However, even with writing minimal script using the plugin, I am not getting any error from the validation.

Please find below the HTML markup along with the validate.js (version 1.13.1) script. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginButton").on("click",function(){
        //alert("logining in....");
        //jQuery Validate Plugin: http://jqueryvalidation.org/ - 24/05/2015
        $("#loginModal").validate({
            rules:{
                username:{
                    required:true,
                    minlength:6
                },
                password:{
                    required:true,
                    minlength:6
                }
            }
        });
    });
});


<div class="modal" id="loginModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalWindowLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="loginModalWindowLabel">Sign In</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form onsubmit="return false;" id="loginForm">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="button" id="loginButton" class="bbcModalbutton pull-right">Login</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <a href="#">Unable to access your account?</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        Don't have an account? <a href="#">Register FREE</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

strong text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your login modal is not in the DOM yet, its a future element, you need to trigger is on a different syntax:

```
$(document).on("click", '#loginButton', function(){
 //your code
}
```

Here is a [fiddle demonstrating the effect](http://jsfiddle.net/bMyGY/1/)

Comment: Should I be validating the form from the #loginModal or from the form's ID?

Comment: jquery validate works on the name attribute, you should validate on the name, not the id, but you can leave it as it is and initiate the validate proccess from the click event from the button

Comment: I am still having problems with this. Everything is loaded on the page. I'm even trying to use validate.js on another webpage that has minimal mark-up and doesn't use bootstrap. What am I doing wrong? I can't see any problems at all.

Comment: `<form onsubmit="return false;"` remove that return false

Comment: It was because I had the button as type "button" and not type "submit". the plugin must require buttons to be type "submit" Thanks Mark

Answer (score 0):

After about half an hour of going back and forward, I finally solved it. If you look at my original post, you will see that I had the login button as type "Button". For some reason, when I changed it to type submit and it worked. I don't understand why but it works.

Thanks Mark for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, the plugin automatically captures the click event of a `type="submit"` `button` or `input`.  Nothing happens when the `type` attribute is not set to `submit`.

Secondly, you don't need to put `.validate()` inside of a `click` handler because the `.validate()` method is only used to ***initialize*** the plugin.  Then after initialization, the `click` event of the submit button is *captured automatically*.  (Nor do you need an inline `onsubmit` event handler.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#loginModal").validate({  // <-- initialize plugin
        // rules & options
         ....
```

The `id` of your `form`, `LoginForm` does not match the selector you attached to `.validate()`, `#loginModal`.

Fixing all of that...

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/654o4wgd/**